# Get text values based on rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this text :

```
var dimensions = "12 H x 45.3 W x 16 G"
```

Now I want to get the value for H & W. If not exists H or W put NULL value.

I tried like

```
 var result = str.split("x");
 var h = result[0].replace('H','');
 var w = result[1].replace('W','');
```

Expected result : h = 12, w = 45.3

The problem is that I can have and W first and H after :

```
var dimensions = "45.3 W x 12 H x 16 G"
```

Expected result : h = 12, w = 45.3

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @TamDc I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get independent values.

```js
const getValue = (s, p) => (s.match(new RegExp('\\S+(?=\\s+' + p + ')')) || [])[0] || null;

var dimensions = "12 H x 45.3 W x 16 G"

console.log(getValue(dimensions, 'H'));
console.log(getValue(dimensions, 'W'));
console.log(getValue(dimensions, 'G'));
console.log(getValue(dimensions, 'F')); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var dimensions = "12 H x 45.3 W x 16 G"
const rs = dimensions.split('x').reduce((acc,e) => {
  let arr = e.trim().split(' ')
  acc.set(arr[1], arr[0])
  return acc
}, new Map())

console.log('H:', rs.get('H'))
console.log('W:', rs.get('W'))
console.log('E:', rs.get('E') || null)
```